# Removing an allocated task from someone

Tags: business-writing

In the software we're developing, the user can '**allocate**' a task to a person or group. Correspondingly he may also take a task away from them. 
 
What word should we use: **unallocate** the task or **deallocate** it?

Comment: Hi Phil, welcome to Writers.SE! I'm afraid we do not allow this type of question - a request to help "find the right word" for something. The problem with such questions is that they clog up the site, and yet are very unlikely to be helpful to anybody else in the future. If you're new to Stack Exchange, take a look at our [intro page](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) and our [FAQ](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Deallocate](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unallocate,%20deallocate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Although you in general **allocate** a **resource** and **assign** a **task** (unless said task is to be treated as a resource, say, helpdesk tasked with resolving that person's troubleshooting ticket).

[image]

You can also *free* or *release* an allocated resource (and correspondingly, *unassign* a task).

Comment: So am I right to infer from what you say that one allocates a resource to a task, and that a task is assigned to a resource?

Comment: @PhilParry: Yes, in case the resource can be a subject - be active, perform the task. A task can be *assigned* to CPU#3 and *committed* to RAM at address X. (CPU is an active resource performing the task. RAM merely contains its data.) In this case though both RAM and CPU are *allocated* for the task. By the way, don't *allocate people*. This is terribly dehumanizing.